# Es posible hacer una consulta a partir del resultado de otra

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta que depende de otra, de acuerdo a un campo del primer select se tendra que hacer otra consulta a una tabla diferente y unir ambas tablas.

```
select (SELECT param1, param2, param3
FROM table_base AS tb
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON tb.id = t2.id
WHERE tb.id = 12) AS tbl, 
 case 
  when tbl.param2 = 1 then (select * from other_table where id = tbl.param1)
  when tbl.param2 = 2 then (select * from other_table where id = tbl.param1)
 end
```

Comment: Revisa las subconsultas en SQL. La consulta interior deberá devolver solo el campo que quieres utilizar en la consulta final. Recuerda usar distinct en caso de varios valores de dicho campo para no repetir valores

Comment: Ese "select (SELECT" está mal hasta donde yo entiendo. En todo caso el select "interno" debería devolver una sola columna.

Comment: Y por lo mismo el resultado del case es un conjunto de filas y por tanto no se corresponde con una columna del primer select.

Comment: Tu verdadero problema, que es como resolver cierta consulta, pero tu pregunta apunta a una solución que has intentado y que es inválida a nivel SQL. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y expliques mejor que es lo que buscas, que tablas tienes y que has intentado. Suerte

Comment: Ah, y de paso me olvidaba: Bienvenido a la comunidad de SOes!